# RxJava 1.x: How to simulate backpressure in unit test

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, backpressure

Given the code:

```
logItemPublisher
    .buffer(
            loggingProperties.getBufferTimeoutMillis(),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            loggingProperties.getBufferSize(),
            logDispatchScheduler
    )
    .onBackpressureDrop(droppedLogsHandler)
    // persist uses Spring RestOperations
    .flatMap(logs -> persist(logs, url)
            .subscribeOn(logDispatchScheduler)
    )
    .subscribe();
```

where,

```
logItemPublisher = ReplaySubject.<AbstractHttpLogItem>createWithSize(4 * loggingProperties.getBufferSize())
                .toSerialized();
logDispatchScheduler = new TestScheduler()
```

I've a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testLogServiceSlow() {
    loggingProperties.setBufferSize(1);
    // rx.ring-buffer.size property stores the size of any in-memory ring buffers that RxJava uses when an
    // Observable cannot keep up with rate of event emissions.
    // default value is 128 on the JVM; RxJava 2.x makes this configurable in flatMap
    System.setProperty("rx.ring-buffer.size", "2");
    // this is what persist does  
    when(restOperations.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(Void.class)))
            .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
            });

    logServiceClient.persistLogs(logs);
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.clearProperty("rx.ring-buffer.size");
    Mockito.verify(restOperations, times(2))
            .postForEntity(Mockito.eq("http://log:9000/log/service"), logsCaptors.capture(), eq(Void.class));
}
```

The test fails because in spite of the `Thread.sleep`, no backpressure is generated. I'm failing to understand why not; the internal ring buffer should fill up after 2 items and the rest of the items should be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
int ringBufferSize = Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("rx.ring-buffer.size"))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .orElse(128);
logItemPublisher
    .buffer(
            loggingProperties.getBufferTimeoutMillis(),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            loggingProperties.getBufferSize(),
            logDispatchScheduler
    )
    .onBackpressureDrop(droppedLogsHandler)
    .observeOn(logDispatchScheduler, ringBufferSize)
    .flatMap(logs -> persist(logs, url))
    .subscribe();
```

Then in the test, simply set `ringBufferSize = 2`, no need to set system property `rx.ring-buffer.size`.